# How to train tensorflow's transformer model on my own data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-translation, attention-mechanism

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/transformer has an implementation of transformer model.
I want to train the model on my own data(consisting of two files, src.txt, and tgt.txt), However, I'm unable to figure out how to provide this input to the model.

I've gone through tensor2tensor and their topic on "train on your own data". I wish to tweak the architecture (not just hyperparameters) and would like to use the model present in **tensorflow/models** repository.
Any idea on how to go about this?